# Runtime Errors in Servlet processRequest Method

Tags: java, jpa, servlets, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I am using JPA, Eclipselink and Servlet in the Netbeans IDE and I have three java files:

1.BankAccount.java: This is my entity file and contains the definition of my bankaccount (this basically maps to the tbl_account table in the database)

```
package banking.entity;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_account")
public class BankAccount{
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="f_id")
private int id;
@Column(name="f_number")
private int number;
@Column(name="f_owner")
private String owner;
@Column(name="f_balance")
private long balance;
public BankAccount() {
}
public BankAccount(int number, String owner, long balance) {
    this.number = number;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.balance = balance;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}
public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}
public String getOwner() {
    return owner;
}
public void setOwner(String owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}
public long getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
public void setBalance(long balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
}
```

2.BankAccountController.java: This file contains the functions for operating on my bankaccount entity file (using JPA and Eclipselink).

```
package banking.controller;
import banking.entity.BankAccount;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;
public class BankAccountController  {
private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
public BankAccountController() {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myJPA");
}
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
public BankAccount findByNumber(int accountNumber) {
    EntityManager em = null;
    BankAccount ba = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        Query q = em.createQuery("select ba from BankAccount ba where ba.number = :num");        
        ba = (BankAccount) q.getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Account Not Found!");
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
    return ba;
}
public void createAccount(BankAccount ba) {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(ba);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
public List findAll() {
    EntityManager em = null;
    List<BankAccount> list= null;
    em = getEntityManager();
    Query q = em.createQuery("select ba from BankAccount ba");
    list = q.getResultList();
    return list;
}
```

}

3.NewServlet.java: In the processRequest method of this file, I want to find the data related to a certain bankaccount (with the number =10) in my database and display its info (including owner's name and its balance) on the browser. Running this file leads to the "NullPointerException". Eliminating ba.getBalance() and ba.getOwner() would resolve the issue. So, the problem lies in accessing the ba object. 
I tested the same piece of code (without eliminating anything) in the main method of a regular .java file and printed the bank account's owner name and its balance on the console and it ran fine.

```
import banking.controller.BankAccountController;
import banking.entity.BankAccount;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet"})
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    BankAccountController baC=new BankAccountController();
    BankAccount ba=baC.findByNumber(10);
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("Balance: " + ba.getBalance());
        out.println("Owner: " + ba.getOwner());
        out.println("</html>");
        out.close();
    }
}
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response)throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response); 
}
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[NewServlet]: Servlet.service() for 
servlet NewServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at NewServlet.processRequest(NewServlet.java:21)
at NewServlet.doGet(NewServlet.java:30)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I would appreciate your comments.

Comment: Kindly add the java code directly instead of screen shots.

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: You did not see this on logs/sysout `System.out.println("Account Not Found!");` by your `BankAccountController`

Comment: @pirho I know this account exists since as I mentioned in my original post, it runs fine in the main method of an ordinary java file. However, "account not found", is the general message printed upon any exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you would debug/log your code a bit more you might see that your query returns `null`. That is because you do not set the parameter `:num` in your query (and you just catch possible exceptions and write to `System.out`):

```
Query q =
    em.createQuery("select ba from BankAccount ba where ba.number = :num");
q.setParameter("num", accountNumber); // THIS IS MISSING
ba = (BankAccount) q.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: You are right. I had mistakenly deleted this line during debugging. I added it. But, that did not solve my problem and I got the same error again. I added the original text of the error to the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that having "System.out.println" in "BankAccountController.java" is causing problems.Eliminating that line solved my problem.